# Logout form Android app using Dreamweaver redirection to url

Tags: php, android, dreamweaver

I am creating an Android app using Dreamweaver and phone gap where I am using login functionality. The login and other task is working properly. But when I am trying to logout, app has been redirected to URL and open a browser kind of thing. My logout link code is:

```
<a href="logout.php" rel="external" data-ajax="false" data-role="none">Logout</a>
```

If I logout from the App, browser should not open, it should under the app and login page should display.

Please help me for this.